# How To Load A website As An Iframe On Button Click and Pass Parameter to it's URL In Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I have two different angular projects. One is a landing page website, while the other is a website where books are being sold.

Landing page component has route parameter in it's URL **(http://localhost:8000/landing/RwgnUvDpEicFA5pWF)** and a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Books</button>
```

I want this button to load the other website were books are sold as an iframe while also passing the route parameter to its' URL, on click.

Does anyone know how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do quite a few steps to get there.

1. Bind a event handler for the button `mouseup` or `click` event.
2. Get current router end-point and append it to your iframe url.
3. Sanitize the iframe url.
4. Set boolean flag to display the iframe.

Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  iframeUrl: string;
  showIframe = false;
  routerSubscription: any;

  constructor(private _router: Router, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public mouseUp(event: any) {
    this.routerSubscription = this._router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(
      event => {
        this.iframeUrl = "url to iframe/" + event['urlAfterRedirects'];
        this.iframeUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.iframeUrl);
        this.showIframe = true;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.routerSubscription) {
      this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Template

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (mouseup)="mouseUp($event)">Buy Books</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="showIframe">
  <iframe [src]="iframeUrl" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Alternative text</iframe>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I couldn't do it the way you explained. But I used some of the ideas you gave here.
I passed the url from the activated routes I subscribed to as the this.iframeUrl . So I had something like this

 this.iframeUrl = `url to iframe${params}/`

This way, It can display different data depending on the url parameter that is in the browser.

Thanks for your answer. It really helped.

Comment: You're welcome. It was only meant to be a placeholder. The question was a little vague to begin with. You say the URL has a parameter, but the example URL you mentioned doesn't contain any. So naturally I assumed you wanted to use the URL end-point.